# Drop-Down Menu SharePoint 2010 - Simple

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu

I want to create a simple drop-down menu with separate options that when selected forward to the associated URL. This is simple in just plain JavaScript but I've run into issues with SharePoint. Are there any solutions using just JS or SharePoint webparts / in browser options (as opposed to coding in Visual Studio or using Designer)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer, you can also use the default "Content Editor Webpart". You can upload a file that contains the needed html, javascript, ... and then use that file as a content source for the Content Editor Webpart. This is a quick way of adding "enhanced" content.

The prefered way would be to create the webpart in Visual Studio, add the needed css and javascript in the package that you deploy  to SharePoint and link the needed files in your webpart.